# perigord test: "authentication needed: password or unlock"?

Tags: migration

Follow these:

- https://decentralize.today/introducing-perigord-golang-tools-for-ethereum-dapp-development-60556c2d9fd
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQZtKf_hzOU

Running `perigord deploy`, enter "blah":

```
Enter passphrase for account 0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A:
Enter passphrase for account 0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A:
Error: [no contract code at given address]
exit status 1
Error: [exit status 1]
```

Running `perigord test`:

```
Running migration 1
Enter passphrase for account 0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FAIL: tests/Foo.go:26: foo_test.TestFoo

tests/Foo.go:28:
    c.Assert(session, NotNil)
... value = nil

Running migration 1
Enter passphrase for account 0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FAIL: tests/TokenERC20.go:19: TokenERC20Suite.SetUpTest

tests/TokenERC20.go:22:
    c.Fatal(err)
... Error: authentication needed: password or unlock


----------------------------------------------------------------------
PANIC: tests/TokenERC20.go:33: TokenERC20Suite.TestName

... Panic: Fixture has panicked (see related PANIC)
OOPS: 0 passed, 2 FAILED, 1 MISSED
--- FAIL: Test (0.01s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/quantonganh/tokendapp    0.065s
Error: [exit status 1]
exit status 1
Error: [exit status 1]
```

Sure, default account has been unlocked:

```
> web3.eth.coinbase
"0x945cd603a6754cb13c3d61d8fe240990f86f9f8a"
> personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase, "blah", 0)
true
```

What is the problem? Is there any configuration where I can config the passphrase for coinbase account?

---

**UPDATE Tue Apr 17 21:39:24 +07 2018**

I added `--unlock` option to [this](https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/master/scripts/launch_geth_testnet.sh#L15) line to unlock the `accounts[0]`:

```
geth --datadir $DIR --unlock 0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A --password $DIR/etc/pw --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --mine --minerthreads 1 --rpc --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal,net" console
```

In the console, I saw this:

```
INFO [04-17|21:38:22] Unlocked account                         address=0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A
INFO [04-17|21:38:22] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A
```

and to confirm:

```
> personal.listWallets
[{
    accounts: [{
        address: "0x945cd603a6754cb13c3d61d8fe240990f86f9f8a",
        url: "keystore:///tmp/geth_private_testnet/keystore/UTC--2017-12-13T18-58-05.147750439Z--945cd603a6754cb13c3d61d8fe240990f86f9f8a"
    }],
    status: "Unlocked",
    url: "keystore:///tmp/geth_private_testnet/keystore/UTC--2017-12-13T18-58-05.147750439Z--945cd603a6754cb13c3d61d8fe240990f86f9f8a"
}, {
```

but `perigord test` still asking me for passphrase, but the prompt does not appear to let me enter:

```
Running migration 1
Enter passphrase for account 0x945Cd603A6754cB13C3D61d8fe240990f86f9f8A:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FAIL: tests/TokenERC20.go:19: TokenERC20Suite.SetUpTest

tests/TokenERC20.go:22:
    c.Fatal(err)
... Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
```

---

**UPDATE Thu Apr 19 21:57:13 +07 2018**

So, my question is why `perigord test` does not wait for an input (I have no chance to enter my passphrase "blah"). That is the reason for "authentication needed: password or unlock".

https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/templates/test/test.go.tpl#L20 -->

https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/testing/testing.go#L40 -->
 https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/migration/migration.go#L115 -->

https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/migration/migration.go#L86 -->

https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/migration/migration.go#L33 -->

https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/templates/migration/migration.go.tpl#L67 -->

https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/templates/migration/migration.go.tpl#L19

Comment: @Downvoter: please leave a comment to let me know the reason.

Comment: Possibly web3.eth.accounts[0] is locked?

Comment: @LinmaoSong I've updated my question. You can see that `0x945cd603a6754cb13c3d61d8fe240990f86f9f8a` is unlocked.

Comment: I wonder if this is a perigord bug. I seem to be able to reproduce. In my case, I attached to the test script's geth instance; and I was able to `eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(100, "ether")})` without entering password. This means the unlock is successful on the geth side.

Comment: Correction to the above "bug" comment, it appears to be by design. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

#### For the updated question

why "perigord test" doesn't take in password input from the terminal?

- Apparently the "test command" is converted to "go test", see [this line](https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/stub/cmd/test.go#L28).
- According to [discussions here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/k__FvI8nW7Q), go-lang unit tests have Stdin connected to /dev/null. This does make sense as unit tests are supposed to be automated.

I might be wrong as I am new to go-lang. It's probably best to discuss with Perigord dev.

#### For the original question

It seems this is expected. The key unlock status in Perigord appears to be ***unrelated*** to the key's status in the remote geth.

Perigord's migration script appears to be generated from a template source file. The template appears to always prompt for passwords, see [this line here](https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/templates/migration/migration.go.tpl#L21). The call to `UnlockWithPrompot` has no conditions like `if unlocked`. Thus, when the test runs the "migration" step, it always asks for a password.

Perigord's KeyStore appears to be a re-use of [this package](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/keystore/keystore.go), which does its own parsing of keystone files (see [function here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/52b046c9b6a0f6a280ff797f90784f76bfd310b9/accounts/keystore/keystore.go#L95)). As a result, even if a key is unlocked inside geth, Perigord has no knowledge of it, as it doesn't rely on underling "web3" calls (unlikely [Truffle Suit](http://truffleframework.com)). Therefore, it has to ask for the password.

In conclusion, unlocking the key from geth has no effect on Perigord.

Comment: The problem is why `perigord test` does not wait for an input? I have no chance to enter my passphrase "blah". That is the reason for "authentication needed: password or unlock". I updated my question.

Comment: My suspicion is, in this line https://github.com/polyswarm/perigord/blob/59155a8da75c95698ac8949b5385e1e4da98702d/network/network.go#L136 the terminal is taken over by the unit test framework.

Comment: _As a result, even if a key is unlocked inside geth, Perigord has no knowledge of it, as it doesn't rely on underling "web3" calls (unlikely Truffle Suit)_ --> Do you mean that `Truffle` rely on underling "web3" calls --> it has knowledge of account status? If so, can `Perigord` be changed to act like `Truffle`?

Comment: Yes, Truffle relies on Javascript APIs - https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/ . In my opinion, the Perigord approach is better, despite it appears to be still in infancy.

Comment: See updated answer. Perigord probably shouldn't prompt for password in unit test mode, as the stdin is connected to /dev/null